# How to use different logging handlers for the same logger in different threads of a python application?

Tags: python, logging

I am using a third-party library (pynetdicom in this case). Logging from modules in the library is generated like this:

```py
LOGGER = logging.getLogger('pynetdicom')
LOGGER.error("Some error message")
```

The library also sets a null handler for the pynetdicom logger, so that no logging is generated by default:

```
logging.getLogger('pynetdicom').addHandler(logging.NullHandler())
```

If I want the modules from the library to generate some logging, I have to override this null handler with some other convenient handler. Up to this point, everything is fine and clear to me.

Now in my application, there are three different threads and they all use modules from the pynetdicom library. I want each thread to log pynetdicom events to different files (i.e. thread1 logs pynetdicom events to thread1.log, thread2 logs pynetdicom events to thread2.log, and so on). How can I accomplish this?

I tried attaching different handlers to the pynetdicom logger in each thread, but of course it didn't work, as they all are modifying the same logger instance, and thus overriding the handler.

**EDIT**

I also tried attaching different handlers to the pynetdicom logger and adding a different filter to each one, which only accepts logs emitted from the desired thread. This didn't work either as pynetdicom creates its own internal threads as part of functions and methods called from my threads.

I also used `inspect.stack()` to capture the entire context of each call to `LOGGER.error('...')` inside pynetdicom and tried to find the original function/module in my application from which the call was generated. This didn't work either, as sometimes the stack finishes in the creation of the pynetdicom internal thread, and no trace of my application modules is found.

**EDIT**

To further clarify the situation, here's an example:

```py
import logging, threading

# Config pynetdicom to log to a file.
logger = logging.getLogger('pynetdicom')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.handlers = []
handler = RotatingFileHandler('dicom_events.log'))
handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s: %(levelname).1s: %(threadName)s: %(message)s ')    
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)

# Functions for each thread in my application
def ServiceClassUser():
    # Some modules from pynetdicom are used from here. They write log messages in 'dicom_events.log'
    
def ServiceClassProvider():
    # Some modules pynetdicom are used from here. They write log messages in 'dicom_events.log'

# Initialize threads
scu_thread = threading.Thread(target = ServiceClassUser, name = 'StoreSCU')
scu_thread.start()

scp_thread = threading.Thread(target = ServiceClassProvider, name = 'StoreSCP')
scp_thread.start()
```

dicom_events.log looks like this:

```
2021-07-12 19:20:05,830: D: Thread-2: Priority                      : Medium 
2021-07-12 19:20:05,830: D: Thread-2: ============================ END DIMSE MESSAGE ============================= 
2021-07-12 19:20:05,830: D: AcceptorThread@20210712191907: pydicom.read_dataset() TransferSyntax="Little Endian Explicit" 
2021-07-12 19:20:05,888: D: Thread-2: pydicom.read_dataset() TransferSyntax="Little Endian Implicit" 
2021-07-12 19:20:07,266: I: Thread-2: Received Store Request 
2021-07-12 19:20:07,266: D: Thread-2: ========================== INCOMING DIMSE MESSAGE ========================== 
2021-07-12 19:20:07,266: D: Thread-2: Message Type                  : C-STORE RQ 
2021-07-12 19:20:07,266: D: Thread-2: Presentation Context ID       : 21 
2021-07-12 19:20:07,266: D: Thread-2: Message ID                    : 1019 
2021-07-12 19:20:07,266: D: Thread-2: Affected SOP Class UID        : 1.2.840.113619.4.30 
2021-07-12 19:20:07,266: D: Thread-2: Affected SOP Instance UID     : 1.2.840.113619.2.131.1460334732.1626124764.739758 
2021-07-12 19:20:07,266: D: Thread-2: Data Set                      : Present 
2021-07-12 19:20:07,267: D: Thread-2: Priority                      : Medium 
2021-07-12 19:20:07,267: D: Thread-2: ============================ END DIMSE MESSAGE ============================= 
2021-07-12 19:20:07,267: D: AcceptorThread@20210712191907: pydicom.read_dataset() TransferSyntax="Little Endian Explicit" 
2021-07-12 19:20:07,291: I: AcceptorThread@20210712191907: Association Released 
2021-07-12 19:20:09,372: I: StoreSCU: Requesting Association
2021-07-12 19:20:09,375: D: Thread-6: Request Parameters: 
2021-07-12 19:20:09,375: D: Thread-6: ======================= OUTGOING A-ASSOCIATE-RQ PDU ======================== 
2021-07-12 19:20:09,375: D: Thread-6: Our Implementation Class UID:      1.2.826.0.1.3680043.9.3811.1.5.7
```

Thread-2, Thread-6 and AcceptorThread are created by pynetdicom. I have no control over them, and I can't find a way to know which call to a pynetdicom module originally created them. So using [Filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#filter-objects) on the originating thread does not help. Neither do using a formatter to include the thread name or id in the log file.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that each of your thread adds a [FileHandler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#filehandler) to the `pynetdicom` logger, then add a [Filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#filter-objects) to each handler to only accept logs emitted from this thread.

Here is an example :

```py
import logging
import threading

logger = logging.getLogger("pynetdicom")
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


class FilterByThread(logging.Filter):
    def __init__(self, allowed_thread_id: int):
        super().__init__()
        self.allowed_thread_id = allowed_thread_id

    def filter(self, record: logging.LogRecord) -> bool:
        return record.thread == self.allowed_thread_id


def setup_thread_logging():
    current_thread_name = threading.current_thread().name
    logfile_name = current_thread_name + ".log"
    handler = logging.FileHandler(logfile_name)
    current_thread_id = threading.current_thread().ident
    log_filter = FilterByThread(current_thread_id)
    handler.addFilter(log_filter)
    logger.addHandler(handler)


def do_main_stuff():
    setup_thread_logging()
    logger.info("hello from Main Thread")


def do_stuff2():
    setup_thread_logging()
    logger.info("hello from thread 2")


def do_stuff3():
    setup_thread_logging()
    logger.info("hello from thread 3")


main_thread = threading.current_thread()
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=do_stuff2, name="thread2")
thread3 = threading.Thread(target=do_stuff3, name="thread3")

thread2.start()
thread3.start()
do_main_stuff()

thread2.join()
thread3.join()
```

which produces :

- `MainThread.log` :

  ```
  hello from Main Thread
  ```
- `thread2.log` :

  ```
  hello from thread 2
  ```
- `thread3.log` :

  ```
  hello from thread 3
  ```

There may be more clever or efficient solutions, but this one is simple to understand.

Comment: Thanks @Lenormju for your help. I had already tried a similar approach but it didn't work. I edited my question with more details about this.

Comment: Another way to solve the problem is to have a Formatter which includes the threadId, so that each log line indicates which thread was responsible for it. Then post-process the file.

Comment: Well unfortunately that does not work either, as pynetdicom creates additional thread over which I have no control. I can't find a way to know which call to pynetdicom modules originally created these additional threads, so knowing the name or id of the originating thread of each log entry does not solve the problem. I posted an example in the question, maybe it helps to clarify the situation. I am really puzzled about this as I know there has to be a way, but I can't find it up to now.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with a filter that creates new handler for each new thread.
Not exactly what was asked, but it was good enough for my purpose.

Took filter snippet from other answer.

```
import logging
import threading
from os import path


class FilterByThread(logging.Filter):
    def __init__(self, allowed_thread_id: int):
        super().__init__()
        self.allowed_thread_id = allowed_thread_id

    def filter(self, record: logging.LogRecord) -> bool:
        return record.thread == self.allowed_thread_id


class AutoThreadFilter(FilterByThread):
    """Automatically Creates separate logger handler for each thread"""

    def __init__(self, logger, logs_path: str, allowed_thread_id: int):
        super().__init__(allowed_thread_id)
        self.allowed_thread_id = allowed_thread_id
        self.handlers = []
        self.logger = logger
        self.logs_path = logs_path

    def filter(self, record: logging.LogRecord) -> bool:
        if super().filter(record):
            return True
        if record.thread not in self.handlers:
            self.create_new_logger(record.threadName, record.thread)
        return False

    def create_new_logger(self, thread_name=threading.current_thread().name, thread_id=threading.current_thread().ident):
        logfile_name = thread_name + ".log"
        handler = logging.FileHandler(path.join(self.logs_path, logfile_name))
        current_thread_id = thread_id
        log_filter = FilterByThread(current_thread_id)
        handler.addFilter(log_filter)
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s: %(levelname).1s: %(threadName)s: %(message)s ')
        handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        self.logger.addHandler(handler)
        self.handlers.append(thread_id)
```

In main class before pynetdicom code:

```
curr_thread = threading.current_thread()
handler = logging.FileHandler(path.join(REPORTS_DIR, curr_thread.name))  # MainThread logger
log_filter = AutoThreadFilter(logger, REPORTS_DIR, curr_thread.ident)
handler.addFilter(log_filter)
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)
```

[image]